# What is the difference between STAssertEqualObjects and STAssertEquals?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocunit

I have the following class:

```
#import "Period.h"

@implementation Period

...

- (BOOL)isEqualTo:(id)object {
    return [self isEqual:object];
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {

    if (object == self) {
        return YES;
    }

    if ([[object beginDate] hash] == [[self beginDate] hash] &&
        [[object endDate] hash] == [[self endDate] hash]) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

...

@end
```

And also the following test, written using `OCUnit`:

```
Period *period;
NSDate *beginDate;
NSDate *endDate;

- (void)setUp {
    beginDate = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2011-02-25"];
    endDate = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2011-03-25"];

    period = [[Period alloc] initWithBeginDate:beginDate
                                       endDate:endDate];
}

- (void)testEndDateShouldBeGreaterOrEqualThanBeginDate {
    Period *newPeriod = [[Period alloc] initWithBeginDate:beginDate
                                                  endDate:beginDate];

    STAssertEqualObjects(beginDate, [newPeriod beginDate], @"Begin dates are different");
    STAssertEqualObjects(endDate, [newPeriod endDate], @"End dates are different");
}
```

Previously I was using `STAssertEquals` instead of `STAssertEqualObjects` and it was not calling `isEqual` method on `Period`.

I just want to understand two things:

- What's the difference between those two methods?
- What's the difference between `isEqual` and `isEqualTo`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`STAssertEquals` compares the raw bytes that make up the two parameters that are passed to it, and is intended to be used with scalar types (`float`, `int`, `char`, etc.), `structs` or `unions`---you should not use it to compare Objective-C objects. `STAssertEqualObjects` compares two Objective-C objects by calling `isEqual:`.

`isEqualTo:` is used to support [`NSSpecifierTest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSSpecifierTest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSpecifierTest) (refer to the [`NSComparisonMethods` Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSComparisonMethods_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)). It is unnecessary to provide an implementation for `isEqualTo:` if your objects aren't scriptable.